# Why do studios release multiple trailers?

Tags: marketing, trailers

Some time back, I saw the trailer for Jurassic World. And I liked it. It built the anticipation and curiosity. But then there was trailer-2 which revealed more scenes, more creatures. Then there was a Super Bowl TV spot, and finally there is a trailer 3. And now, a lot of anticipation and curiosity is killed.

And almost all of the movies are doing this nowadays.

Why do they do that? What's the rationale behind releasing multiple trailers?

I am assuming that this is a new thing and earlier movies just had one trailer.

Comment: I'd surmise it actually *is* to build anticipation and raise public awareness and representation of the movie in the media by more diversity. With each new picture and word of the upcoming movie the public gets more excited about it. It's just an extension of nowadays' trailer and general marketing policy of flooding you with as many stimuli about the movie as possible. And I'd srumise (without proof though) that the majority of people *wants* to see as many different trailers fo the movie, or at least the studios think that to be the case.

Comment: With the depth of media right now, I'd be annoyed if I saw the same exact preview every time I saw an ad on the web, or on TV or before a film at a theater... I think it makes sense... and it's a lot easier to make them now, too.

Comment: Terminator is always worse case, they revealed everything in salvation and now in Genesis.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> **Joker**: Because it's all...part of the [marketing] plan.

The initial trailers are called **teaser trailers** because they're designed to do just that: provide you with a little teaser for the film. These are usually just to announce that a film is coming and to start building anticipation, and possibly because filming isn't quite done or there isn't enough film ready to build a larger, more cohesive trailer. This is also a [marketing stragegy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teaser_campaign) designed to build anticipation for a much larger marketing campaign to come.

The next trailer is usually much larger and reveals a bit more about the overall plot of the film or the ideas behind it. These may be revealed at/during large events such as conventions or even the Super Bowl as you mention.

Usually a month or two before the film is set to come out, there's a final theatrical trailer that's fully intended to give audiences a more concrete and/or complete idea of what the film will be about in an effort to entice them to see it.

Finally, there are also international versions of trailers that are usually tailored to suit the tastes of the local populace, or to highlight something specifically for them. I believe many later ads for the films Inception and the most recent Godzilla film featured Ken Watanebe heavily for the Japanese market, as he's a huge star there.

The point of trailers is to build interest, and marketing behind films is bigger than it's ever been. Even 10 years ago there were only a handful of websites to view movie trailers on, and before that you were beholden to television or going to a movie theater to see them.

Back in the late 90s when the first teaser trailer was announced for the upcoming Star Wars Episode I: The Phantom Menace, and which films it would be attached to (The Siege and A Bug's Life), [people paid full admission price](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Wars_Episode_I:_The_Phantom_Menace#Marketing) to see these films, then walked out as soon as the trailer finished. I remember seeing news reports about theaters putting up signs telling patrons that if they paid to see a movie just to see the Episode I trailer, they would not receive a refund. This isn't an issue anymore because many of them can be released online at a moment's notice, and in some cases are even [leaked online](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avengers:_Age_of_Ultron#Marketing) prior to their planned release.

**Update**: A more recent trend in trailers is to have an approximately 5 second mini trailer for the film that's a super short version of the trailer for the same film shown immediately after.

An example is this trailer for Jason Bourne on YouTube.

The reason for this has to do with how videos like this are usually spread now, through sites like Facebook, Twitter and other social media hubs. Most people will casually scroll through their feeds which now also happen to automatically play video. According to [this article](http://www.cinemablend.com/new/So-Why-Movie-Trailers-Now-Have-Three-Second-Teases-Them-131117.html) on Cinemablend, people tend to only pause for a few moments when they hit a video that autoplays in their feed, so these new short trailers in front of the actual trailer are a new way to capture your attention and quickly tell you what the rest of the 2.5 to 3 minute video is for.