# What is the difference between 'teaser trailer' and 'trailer'?

Tags: john-wick, trailers, john-wick-chapter-4

*John Wick: Chapter 4*'s 'teaser trailer' is out.

I wonder if 'teaser trailer' is different from both 'teaser' and 'trailer'.

Is it a combination of both? Why did they name it 'teaser trailer'?

Comment: Please do some research before asking: https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/33646/why-do-studios-release-multiple-trailers , https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/89505/signifincance-of-trailer-of-the-trailer , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teaser_(trailer) , ...

Answer (score 1):

The words "teaser" and "teaser trailer" are used somewhat interchangabley in this context.

See:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teaser_(trailer)
- https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/33647/96544
- https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/89509/96544)

It's a teaser, in the form of a very short trailer. Teasers aren't necessarily trailers (e.g. [a tweet stating that filming has started](https://twitter.com/michelleparadis/status/1536507640167157760)), but in this case the teaser is a trailer.